# Unable to start MongoDB, (after an improper uninstallation)

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongodb at one location (in D:/abc/software/mongoDB of my PC). Accidentally the parent folder for this installation was renamed and was moved to some other place. I then uninstalled MongoDB (from that new directory, at new location). (Then I realized that the path / location had changed already).

I made a new installation of MongoDB at its default location in C:/ProgramFiles, but now its not working. Whenever I start mongod or shell, it gives error that "mongo has stopped working."

I have tried by uninstallation, re-installation / cleaning the registry with registryCleaner softwares.. But I am unable to run on my PC. So, I need your help.. Any ideas, how to fix this problem.

I shall be thankful to you ..

***Update:***

Find below the content of the two errors found in event log of windows.

Error 1:

> Windows cannot access the file for one of the following reasons: there
>   is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the file is
>   stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the
>   disk is missing. Windows closed the program mongo.exe because of this
>   error.
>
> Program: mongo.exe File:
>
> The error value is listed in the Additional Data section. 
>   **User Action**
>   **1.** Open the file again. This situation might be a temporary problem that corrects itself when the program runs again. **2.** If
>   the file still cannot be accessed and **3.** It is on the network,
>   your network administrator should verify that there is not a problem
>   with the network and that the server can be contacted. - It is on a
>   removable disk, for example, a floppy disk or CD-ROM, verify that the
>   disk is fully inserted into the computer. **4.** Check and repair the
>   file system by running CHKDSK. To run CHKDSK, click Start, click Run,
>   type CMD, and then click OK. At the command prompt, type CHKDSK /F,
>   and then press ENTER. **5.** If the problem persists, restore the file
>   from a backup copy. **6.** Determine whether other files on the same
>   disk can be opened. If not, the disk might be damaged. If it is a hard
>   disk, contact your administrator or computer hardware vendor for
>   further assistance.
>
> Additional Data Error value: 00000000 Disk type: 0

Error 2

> - Faulting application name: mongo.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp:    0x55b66810 Faulting module name: mongo.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time
>     stamp: 0x55b66810 Exception code: 0xc000001d Fault
>     offset:0x00000000003d8f73 Faulting process id: 0x1c84
> - Faulting application start time: 0x01d0d42e6d275be4
> - Faulting application path: C:\databases\mongodb-3.0.5\bin\mongo.exe
> - Faulting module path: C:\databases\mongodb-3.0.5\bin\mongo.exe
> - Report Id: ab41ac54-4021-11e5-8669-2880230266c4

***Update:***

Also I have run the "sfc /scannow" command to fix any integrity violations of windows files, but couldn't find any.

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted file is the config file somehow corrupt?

Answer (score 0):

You can start MongoDB easily from Command Line. I think what you are talking about is the Windows Service. I would just use the command line together with a batch or powershell to start your mongodb manually in case this is only a testing environment.

From the documentation these can help you:

To stop the MongoDB service use the following command:

```
net stop MongoDB
```

To remove the MongoDB service use the following command:

```
"C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe" --remove
```

(source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)

Sometimes the utility Process Monitor helps me. It can see which files and registry keys it accesses before it crashes. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx Did you remove the configuration file too? Is there any virus or fw solution that prevents the application from working?

Comment: Thanks a lot reply Matthias.  I am unable to run mongod at all, as soon as I run mongod, by typing in command prompt or by directly clicking mongd.exe, I face the error that "mongod has stopped working".

I tried to find out in windows event log, I could find below two errors as well.

Please find below the link for the screenshots of the error. May these could let you understand, whats the problem.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3RWcIzK2SbNfjd5aTdfMU5LVlBBX2NWM1NpcUpnQjlEMGxNX1RDaFJPc3JQT19FcmNreFU&usp=sharing

Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately the logs do not help me to understand the issue. See my hint regarding Process Monitor.

Comment: Hi Matthias, can you please give me your email at iawebwork@gmail.com,  so that I can share with you the log file from the ProcessMonitor.

Comment: I think this platform is about Q and A. So in case you have a log file. You should probably post some snippets of it. You could also use Gist to post some of it: https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Hi, find below the links to log files.. 

CSV:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3RWcIzK2SbNXzdOUXRramxCZHc/view?usp=sharing

PML:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3RWcIzK2SbNZ3dWNDlxOWVIZms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I could not find the cause of the issue, but it really looks like the exe or something is corrupt about it. The app crashes before it accesses the registry or anything else.  Is it possible that your HardDrive is full or something?

Comment: It also looks somehow wrong that sometimes this path occurs: \Device\HarddiskVolume2\databases\mongodb-3.0.5\bin instead of C:\databases\mongodb-3.0.5\bin\

Comment: hmm.. I have about 63 GB free out of 100 GB.. 

What can be the issue for this wrong path. how can we fix this?

Comment: I do not know if the path is really wrong or if we are searching in the wrong direction.